# Putting Qt icon on Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: 14.04, qt-creator

How can I put a working Qt5 icon on my Desktop in Ubuntu 14.04? When I try to move it from the Launcher it just jumps back. I can not locate the executable to copy/paste the icon.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Files file manager and browse to `/usr/share/applications`
2. Find the Qt Creator icon in the `/usr/share/applications` directory, copy the Qt Creator icon, and paste it to your Desktop.

Comment: I tried that and can not find anything relating to Qt. The program is there and it runs from the icon in the Launcher. However, I wish to place the icon on the desktop. Any other thoughts appreciated!!

Comment: Mysterious as it may seem, the Qt Creator icon is located in `/usr/share/applications` in my Ubuntu 14.04, alongside many other application icons, having installed Qt Creator from the Ubuntu Software Center. Try this command: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall qtcreator`

Comment: Great! That seemed to do it! No idea why it wasn't there in the first place, or where the one that also works is, but it worked!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but nobody really answered this as others have asked where to place the .desktop file.

QT is installed, normally, into the /opt/Qt directory

Here is an example .desktop file (I named it qtcreator.desktop) which I placed into /usr/share/applications.  I also copied it into the ~/Desktop directory to get it on my Mint Linux and Ubuntu Linux desktops

- [Desktop Entry]
- Name=Qt Creator
- GenericName=Qt Integrated Development Environment
- Comment=Development IDE
- Exec=/opt/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator.sh
- Type=Application
- Keywords=Text;editor;development;IDE;programming
- Icon=/usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/QtProject-qtcreator.png
- Categories=Development;Programming;IDE;